# How to set menu items as active in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii2-basic-app

I'm new to Yii framework..
Now i working with yii1.1.6 version.In admin panel menus i want to display as active menu while which menu item is selected.Please help me how to make menu item as active...

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li class="">
            <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/index'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page',array('site/page', 'view'=>'about')); ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> About Us</a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/contact'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: Which css class have active view? I think if this is bootstrap this is .active class. I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your controller id and action id like this:

```
if(Yii::app()->controller->id == 'site' && Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'index'){
    echo '<li class="active">';
}
```